# cURL taking long time to get the final URL of redirect URL

Tags: php, url, redirect, curl

Below code snippet is to get the final URL(which has media/zip/rar file) from redirect URL by using cURL. It gets the final URL, no doubt about it, but what it does is according to the size of file it varies in time to get URL.

Suppose file at final URL is 1MB, it will take around 5sec to retrieve. But if the file is about 35MB, it takes time about 150 sec. I think cURL is downloading result and finally fetching the URL from result.

```
<?php
echo get_rurl("x_url");//1.2MB -> 5-10sec
//echo get_rurl("y_url");//31.6MB -> 150sec
function get_rurl($url){
    // initialize cURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
    ));
    // execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    // fail if the request was not successful
    if ($result === false) {
        curl_close($curl);
        return null;
    }
    // extract the target url
    $redirectUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $redirectUrl;
}
?>
```

i cant use `file_get_content()` because i just want to get the final URL from given redirect URL.

So in short - how to get the final URL from redirect URL without downloading results.

Hope i make it clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`, but for it the option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` must set to `TRUE`. This is on the grounds that `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` returns precisely what it says, the effective url that ends up getting loaded. If the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=False` then the effective url will be requested url, else it will be final url that is redirected to.

I did this using [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). which gives me information regarding the last transfer

```
<?php
echo get_rurl("xurl");
//echo get_rurl("yurl");
function get_rurl($url){
    // initialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //specify your URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); //disable follow redirects
    $http_data = curl_exec($ch); //hit the $url
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    return $curl_info['redirect_url'];// extract final url
}
?>
```

**or**

Even you can use `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` or `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` depending upon your use cases. refer [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

```
<?php
    echo get_rurl("xurl");
    //echo get_rurl("yurl");
    function get_rurl($url){
        // initialize cURL
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //specify your URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); //disable follow redirects
        $http_data = curl_exec($ch); //hit the $url
        return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps to others users too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of libcurl (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html), this is exactly as is expected when using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,`. You probably want to change this to false.

Comment: it is necessary to be 'true' which will follow redirection to get final URL

Comment: But you don't *want* to follow the redirection. You want to get the redirection url.

Comment: Please try executing above code. By setting it to false, is not working. And i meant to say that, if we follow location then only we will get the final/last-effective-url.

Comment: That is correct. You won't be able to request the CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, but you *will* be able to access the response headers. Which will contain a `Location: ...` header, with the redirection url in it :)